# Google Business performance API: Error: The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-api, gcloud, google-business-profile-api

I am trying to retrieve google performance using the google business performance api based on the documentation of google. I got into this error which says

```
[Nest] 17735  - 04/19/2023, 5:43:22 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] The caller does not have permission
Error: The caller does not have permission
    at Gaxios._request (/Users/nirjalpaudel/Programming/hifoods/node_modules/.pnpm/gaxios@5.0.2/node_modules/gaxios/src/gaxios.ts:158:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at OAuth2Client.requestAsync (/Users/nirjalpaudel/Programming/hifoods/node_modules/.pnpm/google-auth-library@8.7.0/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:382:18)
    at RestaurantPerformanceService.getPerformance (/Users/nirjalpaudel/Programming/hifoods/src/modules/restaurant-performance/restaurant-performance.service.ts:35:18)
```

My code base for the api looks something like this

```js
import { BadRequestException, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Auth, google } from "googleapis";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";

@Injectable()
export class RestaurantPerformanceService {
  OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = this.configService.get("OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID");
  OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = this.configService.get("OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET");
  OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URL = this.configService.get("OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URL");

  oauth2Client: Auth.OAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    clientId: this.OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: this.OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirectUri: this.OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URL,
  });

  SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"];

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  async callBack(code: string) {
    try {
      const { tokens } = await this.oauth2Client.getToken(code);
      this.oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
      return { tokens };
    } catch (e) {
      throw new BadRequestException(e);
    }
  }

  async getPerformance(token: Auth.Credentials, placeId: string) {
    // Acquire an auth client, and bind it to all future calls
    this.oauth2Client.setCredentials(token);

    const resp = await google
      .businessprofileperformance({
        version: "v1",
        auth: this.oauth2Client,
      })
      .locations.fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries({
        dailyMetrics: ["WEBSITE_CLICKS"],
        "dailyRange.endDate.day": 1,
        "dailyRange.endDate.month": 1,
        "dailyRange.endDate.year": 2023,

        "dailyRange.startDate.day": 1,
        "dailyRange.startDate.month": 1,
        "dailyRange.startDate.year": 2023,
        location: `locations/${placeId}`,
      });
    return resp.data;
  }

  async createOauthLogin() {
    try {
      const authUrl = this.oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: "offline",
        prompt: "consent",
        scope: this.SCOPES,
        client_id: this.OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
      });
      return { authUrl };
    } catch (e) {
      throw new BadRequestException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to fix this issue via various other stack overflow questions, but could not find the one which fixes my problem. Can you help me.

The flow look something like this

- createOauthLogin()
- callback()
- getPerformance()

Comment: Is the location that gives the error closed or suspended? The API will give a 403 error if that is the case